# Устранение ошибки django: Unknown field and widget

Tags: python, django

Была необходимость переопределить шаблон для отображения виджета RangeWidget из модуля django_filters. Всё что сделал - убрал лишний символ в шаблоне. Код для нового виджета:

```
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget
class RangeWidgetModify(RangeWidget):
    template_name = 'bgp_app/without_hyphen.html'
```

Вот код, где он используется:

```
...    
action_date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
    label=_('Event date'),
    widget=RangeWidgetModify(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': _('dd/MM/yyyy'),
            'data-form-control': "date",
            'data-date-format': 'd.m.Y'
        })
    )
...
```

Проблема в том, что при заходе на страницу с новым виджетом в консоль выпадает сообщение:

```
/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/material/base.py:216: UserWarning: Unknown field and widget <class 'django_filters.fields.DateRangeField'> <class 'bgp_app.ui.filters.RangeWidgetModify'>
  bound_field.field.widget.__class__))
```

В исходнике, на который указывает ошибка следующий код:

```
except TemplateDoesNotExist:
    # fallback to default field render
    warnings.warn("Unknown field and widget {} {}".format(
        bound_field.field.__class__,
        bound_field.field.widget.__class__))
    return smart_text(bound_field)
```

При этом в целом всё работает. Не понимаю как устранить данную ошибку.

Comment: убедитесь что `bgp_app` есть в конфиге где искать теплейты. Возможно надо положить файл в `bgp_app/templates/without_hyphen.html`

Comment: Шаблонов уже очень много. Если бы он лежал не там где надо - система бы вообще его не воспринимала бы.